# Solutions of the Diophantine equation $x^2(x^2+10)=3y^2(y^2+10)$

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for the solutions of the Diophantine equation 
$$x^2(x^2+10)=3y^2(y^2+10).$$
Is there any solution of this equation except when $(x,y)=(0,0)$?
Or
Any computer programme such as MAGMA could solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

If $x$ and $y$ are not both $0$, let $3^k$ be the highest power of $3$ that divides both $x$ and $y$. Let $x=3^ks$ and $y=3^k t$. Then $3$ cannot be a common divisor of $s$ and $t$.

Substitute and cancel. We get $s^2(x^2+10)=3t^2(y^2+10)$. Since $3$ cannot divide $x^2+10$, it must divide $s$. Say $s=3u$. Then $9u^2(x^2+10)=3t^2(y^2+10)$, and therefore $3u^2(x^2+10)=t^2(y^2+10)$. But then $3$ divides $t$, contradicting the fact that $3$ is not a common divisor of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: Very direct, great proof!

Comment: I think this is in the nature of infinite descent, reflected by your choice of the "highest power of $3$" that divides both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Dear Nicolas, I could not see the proof immediately as you see. Then, what do uou think about the solution of the equations x^2(x^2+10)=3y^2(y^2+6) or x(x+10)=3y^2(y^2+10) or x^2(x^2+10)=3y(y+10). Is the similar method necessary to solve these problems.

Comment: Diophantine equations can be very delicate, a small change can take us from no solutions to infinitely many. Each of the three equations you ask about could be interesting. If you are curious about them, you should ask a formal question about one of them.

Comment: Dear Andre Nicolas, Your method by which the equation  x^2(x^2+10)=3y^2(y^2+10) is solved easily is valid for the equation  x(x+10)=3y^2(y^2+10) or the equation  x^2(x^2+10)=3y^2(y^2+6)?

Comment: The idea does not work for your two new equations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ 3\nmid f(n)=n^2\!+10\:$ since $\rm\ mod\ 3\!:\ n\equiv 0,1,2\ \ but\ \ f(0)\equiv 1,\ f(1)\equiv 2\equiv f(2).\:$ Thus the $3$'s in the unique prime factorization of $\rm\:x^2(x^2\!+\!10)\,$ are those in $\rm\,x^2,\,$ an *even* number, but the $3$'s in $\rm\,3y^2(y^2\!+10)\,$ are those in $\rm\,3y^2,\,$ an *odd* number. Thus $\rm\,x^2(x^2\!+10)\ne3y^2(y^2\!+10)\,$  for $\rm\,x,y\in\Bbb Z.$

**Remark** $\, $ So, ignoring the factors $\rm\,x^2\!+\!10,\ y^2\!+\!10,\,$ which play no role, being never divisible by $3$, the proof is *precisely* the same as one of the standard proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}.$